# python dictionary of lists append to new key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary of lists using integers as key in python. However the following code gives me t is None.

```
t = y.get("1",[]).append(1)
```

(But when I do `counter[c] = counter.get(c,0) + 1`, it will work.)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Comment: append always return None.  don't be surprised about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `None` for `t` with the `append` method is because `append` does not return a value. You can try this instead:

```
t = y.get("1",[])
t.append(1)
```

Comment: Thank  you very much!

Comment: @yuhengd glad to help!